# Powershell catch SQL errors and redirect to log file

Tags: powershell

I've try, catch statement in my powershell to handling errors exception, but below statement didn't output sql error messages to .log file.

```
Try{

Invoke-SqlCmd -InputFile "D:\DropBoxFolder\Dropbox\Public\WIKI_POWERSHELL\AdminTask\ExecutePowerShell_From_BAT\Map_AU.sql"
   }

Catch{
$ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
$Time=Get-Date
"This script failed at $Time and error message was $ErrorMessage" | out-file D:\DropBoxFolder\Dropbox\Public\WIKI_POWERSHELL\AdminTask\ExecutePowerShell_From_BAT\Inovke_SQLScript.log -append
   }

Finally{

$Time=Get-Date
"This script made a read attempt at $Time" | out-file D:\DropBoxFolder\Dropbox\Public\WIKI_POWERSHELL\AdminTask\ExecutePowerShell_From_BAT\Inovke_SQLScript.log -append

$con.Close()
   }
```

Here the errors returned from powershell and I would like to redirect the errors to .log

Invoke-Sqlcmd : There is already an object named 'Map_AU234' in the database.
At D:\DropBoxFolder\Dropbox\Public\WIKI_POWERSHELL\AdminTask\ExecutePowerShell_
From_BAT\Inovke_SQLScript.ps1:49 char:14
+ Invoke-SqlCmd <<<<  -InputFile "D:\DropBoxFolder\Dropbox\Public\WIKI_POWERSHE
LL\AdminTask\ExecutePowerShell_From_BAT\Map_AU.sql"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerS
   hellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShe
   ll.GetScriptCommand

Comment: I think you may have to enclose your `out-file` in quotes as shown here - `$Time=Get-Date
"This script made a read attempt at $Time" | out-file "D:\DropBoxFolder\Dropbox\Public\WIKI_POWERSHELL\AdminTask\ExecutePowerShell_From_BAT\Inovke_SQLScript.log" -append`

Comment: I found out it doesn't go to catch block if error occurs in sql file.

Comment: It works after I added -ErrorAction Stop at the end of Invoke-SqlCmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works after I added -ErrorAction Stop at the end of Invoke-SqlCmd